# Rails 4 has_many view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

In my model a Gainloss has many checks, and I need to create several checks before submiting my GainLoss Model in my form.
I usually do this by creating a collection adding json objects to it and then submiting the form. Which would be the best way to do this in Rails ?
HINT: Im using formtastic.

```
class Gainloss < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "cashflow"
    has_many :operations
    has_many :checks
    belongs_to :account
end

class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gainloss
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= semantic_form_for @gainloss do |f| %>
     <%= f.inputs do %>
         <%= f.input :date, :as => :date_picker, :required => true%>
         <%= f.input :gain, :as => :radio, :collection => [['IN',true],['OUT',false]], :label => 'TX Type'%>
         <%= f.input :description %>
         <%= f.input :account, :collection => Account.all %>
         <%= f.input :cash %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :checks do |check| %>
        <%= check.inputs :date, :bank, :number, :amount, :due, :input_html => { :class => 'form-inline'} %>
<% end%>
<%= f.actions do %>
  <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button , :button_html => { :class => "btn btn-primary" }, :label => 'Guardar' %>
  <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link, :button_html => { :class => "btn btn-default" }, :label => 'Cancelar' %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for  probably what you are looking for.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Nope, not working that way at least not using formtastic.

Comment: nested_attributes_for is normally the way you do this in rails. when setting up it what error messages do you get, what does your controller look like? Did you make sure to allow the nested attributes via strong params?